# how to ask client if he will be using me full time for 2016?

Tags: employment

I am working with a client and he is currently giving me 40 hours of work a week. How do I politely ask him if he will continue to give me full time work for the entirety of 2016 without making waves or making it obvious I may be looking for other employment if his answer is no? There is no contract, work agreement, etc in place.

Comment: It's very simple to ask, as Marv describes below. The question is, without a contract how are you going to be able to trust their answer?

Answer (score 12):

Just say "I'm planning my resource loading and availability for 2016, are you able to give me an idea of your forecast usage requirements for the first [month, quarter, period] and beyond so that I can plan accordingly?"

This is not an unreasonable request.

Comment: awesome answer. would you advise to have them agree to a work agreement or contract for XX number of months? or leave as it is without?

Comment: Just ask the question first and get a commitment to use you. Once you have that you can thrash out the nature of the agreement.

Comment: @MarvMills Just to clarify: did you mean "hash out" or is that an idiom I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Lilienthal I meant "thrash out", apologies I did not realise it was a localised idiom- slang for "negotiate and finalise"...

Comment: @MarvMills No worries, I just wanted to check that it wasn't a typo before using it myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no contract and anything else was handled verbally I think there is no reason to not just grap the phone and have a conversion about this.

It's in no way unreasonable, demanding or pushing, but if you feel unwell asking him directly, I think the most innocuous way to start such a conversation will be beginning it with thanking him for the great collaboration in 2015 and how you enjoyed working for him - this will almost automatically lead the conversation to the topic of his plans for 2016 and which role you will play in this plans.

If you on the other hand really want this to be guaranteed, you'll need to get it written down in a legal binding contract and there will be no other way as to be upfront and honest about it. After all plans are just plans - there is no guarantee his plans won't change.